# sifr 3 r436 javascript error in IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, sifr

I get this error in IE8:

`Object doesn't support this property or method`

on this line.

```
this.results.forEach(function(a){if(!a.views){a.views=0}})
```

I am new to sifr and fairly new to Javascript so I am not sure on what to do here.  If someone could point me in a "helpful" direction that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 2):

You don't get a `forEach` method on arrays in any version of IE so far. `Array.prototype.forEach` is an ECMA-262 Fifth Edition feature which you can't rely on being available: the browser support baseline is Third Edition, where there is no `map`, `filter`, `forEach` or even `indexOf` on arrays.

You can correct this by hacking the `Array.prototype` to add the method if you like. See [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Objects:Array:forEach)'s code, for example. Or, if you are using the prototype library, as you seem to be, you can use `.each`, which hides the difference from you.

[ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) is really hard to read; A useful place to look for the real supported-everywhere baseline for built-in types is in the old [Netscape 4-era JavaScript reference](http://docs.sun.com/source/816-6408-10/contents.htm). Ignore the DOM stuff which is best documented elsewhere, but it's good for the JavaScript built-in types.

Comment: Thanks that helped me narrow it down.  Was actually in the Twitter widget and not in the sifr replacement tool. 

Thanks again

Comment: Thx bobince! You saved me a lot of time :)